# allow users to link their google drive to store data

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

**Node Js**

I want to allow users to store data to their Google Drive account. For that, every user has to link their drive. I also want to access a particular folder or file to show on my website.

Can not find any related information

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that Google drive data is private user data.  Due to that you will need to have the users permission to access their google drive account.  You will need to use Oauth2 have the user login and grant your applicaton access to their google drive account.  then you will have access to any file on the account.   There is no way to link only a single file.

I sugest you look into the [Google apis node.js client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) and start with [Googles Node.js quick start](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) tutorial.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  drive.files.list({
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
      console.log('Files:');
      files.map((file) => {
        console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No files found.');
    }
  });
}
```